# C++ logging wrapper design

Tags: c++, logging

I would like to add a log to my application. I've picked a logging library but I'd like to be able to switch to a different library without having to alter any code that uses logging.

Therefore, I need some sort of logging wrapper that is flexible enough to utilize pretty much any underlying logging library's functionality.

Any suggestions for such a wrapper's design?

EDIT: one feature I must have in this wrapper is component tagging. I want my algorithm class to have "X:" appear ahead of its log lines, and my manager class to have "Y:" appear. How to propagate this these tags onto the underling log and how to build the component tag naming mechanism is one major design question here.

Comment: Do you *really* need a wrapper? Ask that yourself. Is there really the possibility that you're going to switch your logger (multiple times, maybe) or that you'll be utilizing multiple logging frameworks? Writing a wrapper takes resources (time), and they can be put into other things, if you don't *really* need the wrapper.

Comment: thanks, you can trust that I really do. For simplicity's sake I am willing to settle for a very stripped down version of log with the tagging feature I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to make the interface as simple as possible.  Completely separate the logging user's interface from how the logging actually gets implemented.

Cross-cutting concerns always are expensive to maintain, so making things any more complicated will make you hate life.

Some library only wants something simple like this:

```
void logDebug(const std::string &msg);
void logWarning(const std::string &msg);
void logError(const std::string &msg);
```

They shouldn't add or specify any more context.  No one can use the information anyway, so don't over design it.

If you start adding more information to your logging calls it makes it harder to reuse the client code that uses it.  Usually you will see this surface when components are used at different levels of abstraction.  Especially when some low level code is providing debug information that is only relevant to higher levels.

This doesn't force your logging implementation (or even the interface the logging implementation conforms to!) into anything either, so you can change it whenever.

UPDATE:

Insofar as the tagging, that is a high level concern.  I'm going to speculate that it doesn't belong in the log, but that is neither here nor there.

Keep it out of the logging message specification.  Low level code shouldn't give a flying truck who you or your manager is.

I don't know how you specify `X` or `Y` in your example.  How you do that isn't really obvious from the description we are given.  I'm going to just use a string for demonstration, but you should replace it with something type safe if at all possible.

If this is always on, then just having an instance context (probably a global variable) might be appropriate.  When you log in, set the context and forget about it.  If it ever isn't set, throw with extreme prejudice.  If you can't throw when it isn't set, then it isn't always on.

```
void setLoggingContext("X:");
```

If this changes at different levels of abstraction, I would consider a stack based RAII implementation.

```
LoggingTag tag("X:");
```

I'm not sure what your requirements are in the scenario when different stack frames pass in different values.  I could see where either the top or the bottom of the stack would be reasonable for differing use cases.

```
void foo() {
  LoggingTag tag("X:");
  logWarning("foo");
  bar();
  baz();
}

void bar() {
  LoggingTag tag("Y:");
  logWarning("bar");
  baz();
}

void baz() {
  logWarning("baz");
}
```

Either way this shouldn't affect how you add a message to the log.  The `baz` function doesn't have the context to specify the `LoggingTag`.  It's very important that using `logWarning` doesn't know about tags for this reason.

If you wanted to tag based on some type, you could do something simple like this.

```
struct LoggingTag {
  LoggingTag(const std::string &tag_) : tag(tag_) {}
  template<typename T>
    static LoggingTag ByType() {
      return LoggingTag(typeid(T).name());
    }
  std::string tag;
};

void foo() {
  LoggingTag tag = LogginTag::ByType<int>();
}
```

This wouldn't *force* someone to use `typeid(T).name()` if they didn't want to, but gave you the convenience.

Comment: One concern I have to account for is different component tagging.

Comment: I had this syntax in my mind: Log log = GetLogger(MyClassName); log.Warn(...). I'm not sure about what MyClassName should be, if it's a string, where do I get it from? If it's some trick to convert a class name to a string, how can it be done?

Comment: @user991339 I don't understand what you are asking at all.  Are you trying to log a type?

Comment: No, I would like to associate a tag name with a class that uses the log

Comment: @user991339 Updated with how I would go about it.  You want logging to be declarative, using log objects as you offered conflicts with that and will be harder to maintain.

Comment: LoggingTak with a global variable won't do. It's not threadsafe.

Comment: @user991339 I can't guess at your threading situation, though I only offered a global for the one instance where the data never changes.  You can just copy it to each thread in that instance.

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach:

```
class Log {
public:
    virtual logString(const std::string&)=0;
};

template <typename T>
Log& operator<<(Log& logger, const T& object) {
        std::stringstream converter;
        converter << object;
        logger.logString(converter.str());
        return logger;
}
```

Simple and quick! All you need to do is reimplement the logString method...

Comment: This is a fine idea. Can you suggest a way to implement the tagging feature?

Comment: @user991339 I would add a Tag attribute to the logger and a bool to indicate a start-of-line so on first log it gets the tag stamp. You may specialize the operator<< for the endl case so you know that next input is a start of line.

Comment: How does Boost.Log know when to print the line without bools or endls?
log<<"now for sure";
log<<"now?"<<"or maybe now?";

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [zf_log](https://github.com/wonder-mice/zf_log) library. It is very small (~2000k lines, ~10KB when compiled) and fast (see comparison table in [README.md](https://github.com/wonder-mice/zf_log/blob/master/README.md)). It is very close to what you describe as wrapper. It gives you an abstract API that you can use in your project and allows to specify what actual logging implementation to use. See [custom_output.c](https://github.com/wonder-mice/zf_log/blob/master/examples/custom_output.c) example where syslog is used as output facility. It also could be used privately inside libraries without risk of getting into conflict with other code that could use this library (see [ZF_LOG_LIBRARY_PREFIX](https://github.com/wonder-mice/zf_log/blob/master/zf_log/zf_log.h#L293) define for more info).
Even if it's not exactly what you are looking for, I guess it could be a good example for your wrapper thing.